# Dojo Event dynamically created events not handled

Tags: javascript, html, events, web, dojo

I  have the following Dojo Javascript snippet:

```
postCreate: function () {
    this.inherited(arguments);
    var hitchWidgetToaddLevelButtonClickHandler = DojoBaseLang.hitch(this, addLevelButtonClickHandler);
    DojoOn(this.AddLevelButton, "click", hitchWidgetToaddLevelButtonClickHandler);

    function addLevelButtonClickHandler() {
                hierarchyLevelNumber += 1;
                var myButton = new Button({
                    label: "Click me!",
                    id: "level_button_" + hierarchyLevelNumber,
                    onClick: function(){
                        // Do something:
                        console.log("Hello there, ");
                    }
                }).placeAt(someNode,"last").startup();

                    var registeredRemovalButton = DijitRegistry.byId(("level_button_" + hierarchyLevelNumber));
                    DojoOn(registeredRemovalButton, "click", function someFunction() {
                        console.log("how are you?");
                    });
    }
}
```

and the following HTML

```
<div id="settingsBorderContainer" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design:'headline', gutters:false, region:'top'" class="${theme}">

    <table data-dojo-attach-point="HierarchyLevelsTable">
        <tr>
            <th>Level</th>
            <th> Table Name </th>
            <th> Column Name</th>
        </tr>
        <td id="someNode">
        </td>
    </table>
</div>
```

The goal here is, when AddLevelButton is clicked it dynamically creates a row in the table with the necessary information and a new button for each row. Note that the HTML and Javascript are largely simplified to illustrate my problem. I did not include all of the row logic that occurs in `addLevelButtonClickHandler()` method. The HTMl is built as intended, as you can see in the following screenshot:[image: ButtonTable]

The problem is that everytime I add a button, only the last button's event listeners work, i.e. in the case of the screenshot the button circled in red logs: `Hello there, you called the remove handler [object MouseEvent]`, and the previous button in the table no longer can be clicked and catch the necessary event. Sorry if the code is a gross-simplification of my goal, I appreciate any help that is offered.

*********EDIT**************

So I took a different approach and placed only 1 button total, and delete level by level from the bottom up. As long as it resides outside of a `<table>` it functions..Which brings me to the conclusion of **NEVER PUT DIJITS OR BUTTONS IN A TABLE** After many hours lost, I would recommend if you absolutely need a table in the first place, just placing the button next to the table as necessary using [CSS and floats](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp) 
I will leave this question as unanswered until someone may be able to offer an explanation of why the inner table approach does not work.

Comment: The issue doesn't seems to be in code shared above. My guess is, some issue while adding rows. Are you using `innerHTML` while creating the rows?

Comment: No, each single row has three <td> elements and (reflecting text) and another <td> which the button is placed into. Here is the [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cahzxg1o/)  with a row from the table of the type of HTML which is generated and some more javascript to see how it was done. Do you see any obvious problems?

Comment: the JS fiddle does not contains any javascript code.

Comment: @TKambi [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cahzxg1o/3/)

Comment: You are using `this.HierarchyLevelsTable.innerHTML`. By updating the `innerHTML` you are destroying the dom Nodes to which the events were attached.

Comment: Thank you @TKambi
Would you be kind enough to make a formal reply and I can mark this as answered? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While working with dojo. You should never use `node.innerHTML` to add or update nodes. It will basically convert all the dijits into HTML string and parse as regular HTML by the browser. which in turn will destroy dom object and event associated to it.

Instead create dom object using `dojo/dom-construct` and add it with `appendChild` for DOM nodes or `addChild` in case of container dijits.

Comment: In my case, the Dijit nodes (buttons) were being added to the table through rows which were created through an append operation of the table's `innerHTML` property which resulted in the buttons' event listeners to be destroyed as T Kambi explained aboved!